# Shrink PDF pages

Tags: pdfsharp

How to shrink PDF page ?

```
                 XSize xsizes = PdfSharp.PageSizeConverter.ToSize(PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);

                if (page.Orientation == PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape)
                {
                    page.Width = xsizes.Height;
                    page.Height = xsizes.Width;
                }
                else
                {
                    page.Width = xsizes.Width;
                    page.Height = xsizes.Height;
                }
```

This code cropped pdf page from right side, so content of page cropped from page.Need solution to shrink page without crop content.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _shrink_. Do you want a smaller file size? Do you want the page size as measured in physical units to decrease? If you want a smaller page size will you scale the contents or do you want to crop the margin?

Comment: Shrink means convert pdf page to A4 size page. For Example..  when page width and height is too large to fit into A4 size page  than than there is an option in print to shrink page. I need to do that using pdfsharp library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new page of the desired size, then draw the existing page like an image on that new page at the position and with the size you want.

The Two Pages on One sample shows the methods you need:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/TwoPagesOnOne-sample.ashx
You just have to adapt the code to draw one page on one, but adjusting the page size in the process.